# Program with linked card in OpenComputers (minecraft)

Tags: lua, minecraft, opencomputers

I am trying to make a system where a server and a computer talk to each other from a great distance. This is not possible with wires as they need to pass trough unloaded chunks. A linked card has unlimited reach, but isn't programmed the same way as a network card is...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shEtb.png)

A Linked card doesn't use modem, so I don't know how to communicate between them

Is there any way to communicate between these computers and servers without a linked card, or is there any wat to fix my code?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode I'm a bit confused about the question, is a network card an option? Then use it. If not use a linked card. A linked card is a tunnel, or channel, and is basically a simpler way of communicating. Check out https://ocdoc.cil.li/component:tunnel

Comment: The code I wrote for a network card doesn't work on a linked card, because there "is no modem". I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: Because it is no modem. I send you the doc, read it, it's well described. If you still have questions after that update the question with the code you got.